# Specify range of image widths and or height in Nokogiri css selector

Tags: ruby, parsing, css-selectors, nokogiri

I would like to use this CSS selector but rather than specify the EXACT width and height of the image, I need to pick a minimum or maximum or a range for width and/or height. I'm using the Nokogiri gem in Ruby, is there any way to do this?

```
img = doc.css("img[@width = '#{width}'][@height = '#{height}']").collect{|e| e.attributes["src"].value}
```

For example width > 200 etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what the self.body is all about but you can select img's by width like so:

```
doc.css('img').select{|img| img[:width].to_i > 200}
```

or

```
doc.css('img').select{|img| (200..300).include? img[:width].to_i}
```

Comment: what if the width/height attribute of image is missing? can we still calculate the width/height?

Comment: @Bongs No, in that case you would need to download the image to determine the dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

```
doc.xpath('//img[@width > 200]/@src').map {|a| a.value }
```

or

```
doc.xpath('//img[@height >= 50 and @height <= 300 and @width >= 50 and @width <= 300]/@src').map {|a| a.value }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can´t give you an exact solution, but I think you should be able to do this in Nokogiri by using [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath_2.0).

The [function library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath_2.0#Function_library) provides min/max functions.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions already provided involve either using css and filtering the results with Ruby, or using xpath where you can make use of xpath functions to filter the nodes you're interested in.

With Nokogiri there is another technique that might be useful, you can define your own [custom css pseudo classes](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-css) that you can then use in your selectors. For example you could define a `height_greater_than` pseudo class and then use a selector like `img:height_greater_than(200)`.

You do this by defining a (Ruby)class with methods for the pseudo (css)classes you want to implement. Each method should take a [`NodeSet`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet.html) as its first argument, then whatever arguments you want to pass from the css.

```
class CustomPsuedoSelectors
  def height_greater_than(nodes, height)
    nodes.find_all {|n| n['height'].to_i > height}
  end
end
```

Next pass an instance of this class as an argument to the call to `css`:

```
nodes = doc.css 'img:height_greater_than(200)', CustomPsuedoSelectors.new
```

It might not be worth doing this for a single query, but if you're making selections like this a lot, and you prefer the css syntax over using xpath, it might be worth creating some custom classes like this.

One final thing, since css tends to use hyphens rather than underscores, you might want to create aliases for your methods, e.g. add `alias :"height-greater-than" height_greater_than` after the definition of `height_greater_than`. Then you can use the more natural `img:height-greater-than(200)` as your css selector. (You could also use `define_method`).